# Keycloak & JavaEE (UserPrincipal)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaas, keycloak

I start a new Web-Project and I plan to use Keycloak Identity and Access Management Server.

I use:

- Keycloak 2.5.5 / 3.0.0.0 RC
- Wildfly 10
- JavaEE 7

My Problem I try to create my own Login/Register page.

### Login with Keycloak page

If I use the Login page of Keycloak, I can login, has access to the use information on my UserPrincipal.
I can Read the user with:

```
Principal userPrincipal = request.getUserPrincipal();
userPrincipal.getName();
```

Or I can logout with

```
request.logout();
```

### Login with own calls

If I try to Login with

```
AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create(...)
authzClient.authorization("username", "password");
```

or

```
Map<String, String> reqHeaders = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> reqParams = new HashMap<>();
ClientCredentialsProviderUtils.setClientCredentials(deployment, reqHeaders, reqParams);
for (Map.Entry<String, String> header : reqHeaders.entrySet()) {
   post.setHeader(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
 }
 for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : reqParams.entrySet()) {
   formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(param.getKey(), param.getValue()));
        }

 UrlEncodedFormEntity form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, "UTF-8");
 post.setEntity(form);

 HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

I get the Valid user but I can't use the UserPrincipal. UserPrincipal is always null.

### Questions

- How I can Login with my own form on Keycloak Server and has access over UserPrincipal?
- How works the connection beetween JavaEE/JAAS and Keycloak (Client Adapters)?
- How use JAAS with Keycloak?